# Where do lifecycle methods, and other methods, get their parameter values?

Tags: java, android, android-lifecycle, fragment-oncreateview, activity-oncreateview

In the following Android lifecycle method:

```
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(
      LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    ...
    return view;
  }
```

onCreateView takes in a  ‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍`LayoutInflater`, `@Nullable Viewgroup`, and a `@Nullable Bundle`.
The issue I have is in the sample program I am referring to: [sceneform-android-sdk](https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/blob/master/samples/augmentedimage/app/src/main/java/com/google/ar/sceneform/samples/augmentedimage/AugmentedImageFragment.java#L85)

There doesn't seem to be an instance where we call the method `onCreateView` and pass in a LayoutInflatter, Viewgroup, and Bundle. And yet, we are able to use the passed in parameters.
Yes we call `super.onCreateView(...)`, but again, where did the values passed as ***arguments*** to the super, that were the ***parameters*** of our `local` version of onCreateView, come from?

My main question, reiterated, would be what is it that calls the onCreateView method and passes in the parameters?
My second question is, if I were to create a method in the same activity onCreateView is in:

```
public void foo(LayoutInflater myInflater) // Or it takes in a Bundle, Viewgroup, etc.
```

Would my foo method also get the same parameter values as the onCreateView method?
Lastly, my third question would be in a similar vein. A view is returned, but like before, it doesn't look like we handle the return. So, what handles the return value??
If possible, I would humbly request further reading regarding how Android core code works so as to implement my own methods that properly make use of
parameters from Android and how to properly return values to Android as well.

Comment: *"what is it that calls the onCreateView method"* - the framework, Android's core code. Same answer to Q3. And to Q2: no, the framework only calls the methods it knows about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation for `Fragment.onCreateView()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment.html#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20android.os.Bundle)) indicates the following:

> This will be called between onCreate(Bundle) and
>   onActivityCreated(Bundle).

The Android framwork makes all lifecycle calls itself.The Android framework will call `onCreate()` on the fragment`to initialize the fragment. At some later time, the Android framework will call`onCreateView()` on the fragment. The following parameters are passed:

- `LayoutInflater`: The `LayoutInflater` object that can be used to inflate any views in the `Fragment`. The framework gets the `LayoutInflater` from the `Activity`'s `Context`.
- `ViewGroup`: If non-null, this is the parent view that the fragment's UI should be attached to. The fragment should not add the view itself, but this can be used to generate the `LayoutParams` of the view. This parameter is the container `View` that holds the `Fragment`.

`Bundle`: If non-null, this fragment is being re-constructed from a previous saved state as given here. In this case, the `Bundle` contains the most recently saved state of the `Fragment` (ie: the data from the most recent call made to the `Fragment`s `onSaveInstanceState()` method).

Regarding your other questions:

- If you define a method `foo()`, the Android framework would never call it. The Android framework has a specific set of defined methods that it calls on certain components (`Activity, Service, BroadcastReceiver, Fragment`, etc.) at specific times.
- The `View` returned from `onCreateView()` will be used by the Android framework. The documentation clearly indicates how the returned `View` object is used:

> If you return a View from here, you will later be called in
>   `onDestroyView()` when the view is being released.